# ExecWait not executing in 2nd section

Tags: windows-installer, nsis, sections

I have an NSIS script in which I am executing the same .exe with different parameters in sections. for example, let say I have abc.exe which is properly getting executed in section 1, but in section 2 it's not completely getting executed. Can anybody please suggest any help?

> 

```
Section "Module1"
 SectionIn 1
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR/config
  SetOverwrite off
   File "abc1.xml"
    ExecWait '"INSTDIR/abc.exe" -c "demo1.xml""'
Section End

Section "Module2"
 SectionIn 2
  Setoutpath $INSTDIR/config
  SetOverwrite off
   File "abc2.xml"
    ExecWait '"INSTDIR/abc.exe" -c "demo2.xml"'
Section End
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your code contains a suspicious typo, post your real code. Why are you using `SectionIn`?

Comment: Thanks @Anders. As I am having different modules to be installed using same .exe but with different config xml parmeters hence I am using SectionIn 1, SectionIn 2,… etc. I have updated the script.

Comment: I just need to be sure the other section is actually executed. What happens if you put a `MessageBox` in that section?

Comment: Yes, @Anders, They are getting executed I confirmed it but putting messagebox but only the .exe not completely being executed as its properly executed in 1st section. I also confirm this from logs. So according to the log from section 2 execwait is running only for certain steps till the last section.